# Rewrite url /powers/power.php?power=

Tags: htaccess, redirects

I want to rewrite my url, the url uses a variable I think its called, but I want to shorten the url to http://xatwebs.co/powers/gold as it is currently http://xatwebs.co/powers/power?power=gold I have search for rewrite methods but the ones i have tried has either broke it completely or made a loop redirect making the page non viewable

```
Redirect 301 /trusted http://community.xat.com/showthread.php?28330-Prize-Holders
Redirect 301 /forums http://xatwebs.co/forum
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# force url to lowercase
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
# ensure it is not a file on the drive first
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteRule (.*) rewrite-strtolower.php?rewrite-strtolower-url=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteEngine on
#
# If requested URL-path plus ".php" exists as a file
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
# Rewrite to append ".php" to extensionless URL-path
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*[^.]+)$ /$1.php [L]

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
ErrorDocument 403 /403.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xatwebs\.co$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.xatwebs\.co$
RewriteRule ^notice1$ "http\:\/\/assistance\.xatwebs\.co\/general\/inactivity\-notice\/" [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^powers/(.+)$ /power.php?power=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

**Update:** I think I have fixed it by using this code as it allows me to do `xatwebs.co/powers/red` but it doesn't redirect from `xatwebs.co/powers/power.php?power=red`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.xatwebs.co
RewriteRule (.*) http://xatwebs.co/powers/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ power.php?power=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ power.php?power=$1
```

Comment: Have you already changed all your in page links to use the new URLs?

Comment: Yes, but I want to make it if its possible to redirect them to new link

Answer (score 1):

You only need `RewriteEngine On` once at the top of your .htaccess file.

Always have external redirects *before* internal rewrites.

So, in order to *redirect* from the "ugly" (`/powers/power.php?power=red`) URL to the "pretty" (`/powers/red`) URL (in order to satisfy search engines and anyone who has linked to your site), you could do something like this:

```
# Redirect typed querystring URLs to "pretty" URLs
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?power=([^\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^powers/power\.php$ /powers/%1? [R=301,L]
```

This checks against `THE_REQUEST` to avoid a potential rewrite loop (caused by the following rewrite).

Then to *internally rewrite* from the "pretty" URL back to the "ugly" (real) one, something similar to what you have after your update:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^power=
RewriteRule ^powers/(.*) /powers/power.php?power=$1 [L]
```

Although, from your examples, it's a bit unclear whether `/powers` is part of the URL or not (you mention it in the description but it appears to be omitted from your "working" update)? So this may need adjusting. This also replaces your extensionless URLs code snippet as well.

Don't rewrite direct requests for files that already exist on the filesystem - just in case you have scripts or stylesheets that match this pattern. Also this doesn't rewrite requests that already have the query string parameter.

Make `(.*)` more restrictive if you need to.